# Promise chains are not executed sequentially using Q promise library

Tags: javascript, promise, deferred, q

I am performing multiple batched asynchronous operations in my code. Although operations within a batch should execute asynchronously batches should be executed synchronously one after another.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qp2c4/) I created. Look at the console as all output is there. And here is the code for convenience:

```
asyncChain(10, 'FIRST CHAIN')
.then(function () {
  asyncChain(10, 'SECOND CHAIN');
})
.then(function(){
  asyncChain(10, 'THIRD CHAIN');
});

function asyncChain(n, msg) {
  var promiseChain = Q.fcall(function () {
    10;
  });
  console.log('starting:' + msg);
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    promiseChain = promiseChain.then(asyncOperation(i, msg));
  }
  console.log('returning' + msg);
  return promiseChain;
}

function asyncOperation(i, msg) {
  var d = Q.defer();

  setTimeout(function () {
    console.log('resolving for #' + i + msg);
    d.resolve(i);
  }, 300 + Math.random()*1000);

  return d.promise;
}
```

Basically these are 3 batched promise operations I expect to be finished one after another. Meaning the output for this sample would be something like this:

```
starting FIRST CHAIN
returning FIRST CHAIN
resolving 1..10 FIRST CHAIN

starting SECOND CHAIN
returning SECOND CHAIN
resolving 1..10 SECOND CHAIN
and so on
```

I tried using `all()` method instead of `then()` but it stopped execution after first chain. Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks for any advice.

Cheers

Comment: Within the batches, by "asynchronous" you still mean "sequentially", not "parallel"?

Comment: I meant the latter one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Am I missing something obvious?

Yes. For `then` to resolve the promise with another promise, you have to *return* that other promise to it. Your function does just start another `asyncChain`, but returns `undefined` from the callback which resolves the promise immediately.

```
asyncChain(10, 'FIRST CHAIN').then(function () {
  return asyncChain(10, 'SECOND CHAIN');
}).then(function(){
  return asyncChain(10, 'THIRD CHAIN');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, I think I just spent too much time staring at the same code :) I have also found that using 'thenResolve' method makes the syntax a bit more readable and the anonymous functions does not have to be defined.

Comment: But `thenResolve` does not wait for the first promise before it evaluates `asyncChain(…)`, making it parallel again?

Comment: thenResolve() is just a sugar for function(){}. Check it out in the <a href='https://github.com/kriskowal/q/blob/master/q.js'> source -</a> line 846.

Comment: Yeah, but there's a huge difference when `value` is evaluated… When `asyncChain` is called before the result is passed into [`thenResolve`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/blob/master/q.js#l846), all the calls will be executed parallel. When it is called in the anonymous function that is passed to `then`, they will be executed sequentially.